# Does applecelrator titanium have powered by appcelerator splash screen or other watermarks?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

I am new to app development and I am really looking for the best software to build apps. I wanted to know if appcelerator has any watermarks included for the free version. I saw the old ide but I am not sure if the new ide has the same watermark/splash screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no watermarks embedded in your app when using the [Indie Seat](https://www.appcelerator.com/pricing/) license (free version).

When you create a new mobile app (File > New Project) there will be some default splash screens (required by apple/android) with the Appcelerator logo in the appropriate os-named folder. You simply need to create your own splash screens and replace the defaults.

Appcelerator is a great choice if you you know javascript, or start with Xamarin if you are a C# guy.